Drizzle creating relational queries and undefined 'referencedTable' error
I am learning drizzle while using NextJs and I can't figure out the problem with my queries that includes relationships. Problem is: 
When creating a db connection as follows
import { config } from "dotenv";
import { drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/postgres-js";
import postgres from "postgres";
import { notes, files } from "../../drizzle/schema";

config({ path: ".env" });

const connection = postgres({
    host: process.env.PG_HOST ?? "localhost",
    port: Number(process.env.PG_PORT) ?? 5432,
    user: process.env.PG_USER ?? "postgres",
    password: process.env.PG_PASSWORD ?? "",
    database: process.env.PG_DATABASE ?? "postgres",
});
const db = drizzle(connection, {
    schema: { notes, files },
    logger: true,
});
export default db;

Which gives the following error: "Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'referencedTable')"

I can solve this with the following code:
import { config } from "dotenv";
import { drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/postgres-js";
import postgres from "postgres";
import { notes, files } from "../../drizzle/schema";

config({ path: ".env" });

const connection = postgres({
    host: process.env.PG_HOST ?? "localhost",
    port: Number(process.env.PG_PORT) ?? 5432,
    user: process.env.PG_USER ?? "postgres",
    password: process.env.PG_PASSWORD ?? "",
    database: process.env.PG_DATABASE ?? "postgres",
});
const db = drizzle(connection, {
    schema: { ...notes, ...files },
    logger: true,
});
export default db;

The difference between these 2 codes are the line schema: {}, in the first one I use as schema: { notes, files } which gives the first error, and using it as schema: { ...notes, ...files } can solve this problem.
The following code gives the error "Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findMany')" becasue db.query is an empty object.
export async function fetchNotes() {
    return await db.query.notes.findMany({
      with: {
        files: true
      }
    })
}

The actual problem is when I want to use db.query so I can select with relations, if I try to solve the first problem with schema: { ...notes, ...files } line, db.query object becomes empty {} (object).
I read everything that I found but still, cannot figure out the problem.
Following snippets are files that associated with drizzle:
file: drizzle.config.ts
import "dotenv/config";
import { defineConfig } from "drizzle-kit";

export default defineConfig({
    dialect: "postgresql",
    out: "./drizzle",
    schema: "./drizzle/schema.ts",
    dbCredentials: {
      host: process.env.PG_HOST ?? "localhost",
      port: Number(process.env.PG_PORT) ?? 5432,
      user: process.env.PG_USER ?? "postgres",
      password: process.env.PG_PASSWORD ?? "",
      database: process.env.PG_DATABASE ?? "postgres",
    },
    verbose: true,
    strict: true,
});


file: drizzle/schema.ts
import { relations } from "drizzle-orm";
import { text, serial, pgTable, integer } from "drizzle-orm/pg-core";

export const notes = pgTable("notes", {
    id: serial("notes_id").primaryKey(),
    title: text("notes_title").unique().notNull(),
    description: text("notes_description").notNull(),
});


export type NoteWithFiles = SelectNotes & { files: SelectFiles[] };
export type SelectNotes = typeof notes.$inferSelect;
export type InsertNotes = typeof notes.$inferInsert;

export const files = pgTable("files", {
    id: serial("files_id").primaryKey(),
    title: text("files_title").notNull(),
    language: text("files_language").notNull(),
    body: text("files_content_body").notNull(),
    noteId: integer("note_id").references(() => notes.id, {
      onDelete: "cascade",
    }).notNull(),
});

export const notesRelations = relations(notes, ({ many }) => ({
    files: many(files),
}));

export const filesRelations = relations(files, ({ one }) => ({
    note: one(notes, {
      fields: [files.noteId],
      references: [notes.id],
    }),
}));

export type FileWithNote = SelectFiles & { note: SelectNotes };
export type SelectFiles = typeof files.$inferSelect;
export type InsertFiles = typeof files.$inferInsert;

export const schema = { notes, files };


Find out the problem, turns out drizzle documentations can be misleading this code-block shows drizzle db connection as const db = drizzle(client, { schema: { ...schema1, ...schema2 } }); which is wrong, you need to import the file as schema and use it as an argument for drizzle function.
Wrong example
const db = drizzle(client, { schema: { ...schema1, ...schema2 } });

Corrected version
import * as schema from "path/to/schema";
const db = drizzle(connection, { schema });

